# numpy: copy some elements of two arrays into another array

Tags: numpy

I have two arrays and I am hoping to create an additional array which will copy the some values in the two arrays:

```
a = np.array([1,-2,-3,-3])
b = np.array([-2,1,-3,-2])
```

Hoping to get:

```
np.array([1,1,-3,-2])
```

I'm just trying to get the value 1 from both arrays into another array. The copying of the negative numbers doesn't matter as they get masked down the road.

Comment: Hey, you need to elaborate the question a bit more. Where are you using `a` and `b`? Values at which indices of `a` and `b` are you expecting to copy? What is your thought process behind expecting `np.array([1,1,-3,-2])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @shridhar-r-kulkarni for asking for more detail rather than simply down voting. It jogged my thinking so I could work it out.

```
a = np.array([1,-2,-3,-3])
b = np.array([-2,1,-3,-2])
c= np.full_like(a, np.nan, dtype=np.double)
# Find which indices in a has values > 0
c[np.where(a > 0)] = a[np.where(a > 0)]
# Find which indices in b has values > 0
c[np.where(b > 0)] = b[np.where(b > 0)]
# c is array([  1.,   1.,  nan,  nan])
```